# problem with if statement using length function for filtering strings in python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, string-length

I am trying to make a function which reviews all input words (variable amount of words using args) and returns all words over 10 characters long.

Here is my code:

```
def big_words(*n): #'*' allows variable amount of arguments

"""function to provide list of words with more than 10 characters.
allows multiple words to be processed"""

    return [item for item in n if len(str(n))>10]

big_words('substantiation', "boss", 'wallower', 'substantiation')
```

expected output:

```
['substantiation', 'substantiation']
```

actual output:

```
['substantiation', 'boss', 'wallower', 'substantiation']
```

why is the function not removing 'boss' and 'wallower'?

I am new to coding so all help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your if statement is asking for the length of n as a string, not the length of the word

```
return [item for item in n if len(item) > 10]
```

Comment: This is also a good illustration of why naming is important. If `n` had been named `items`, the bug would be pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed `n` and `item`. See below for a working solution.

Note that the variable names were modified in order to make the code clearer.

```
def big_words(*words):
    return [word for word in words if len(word) > 10]


print(big_words('substantiation', "boss", 'wallower', 'substantiation'))
```

Comment: ```len((item))``` the two parenthesis is unnecessary